# How can I make my text in my HTML responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So my images and boxes respond to the browser window size when I shrink it down but the text doesn't. I have tried many different things: percentages, ems and media queries but none seem to work. Maybe I am placing them wrong?

Here is the code for the CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    background: #394BA0;
    color:#C180E4;
    border-color:#88C6ED;
}
#wrapper {
width:62.7%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    height: 1199px;
}
#header {
border:1px solid #bbb;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
}
#content-left {
width: 21%;
height: 61.4%;
border:1px solid #bbb;
float: left;
margin-top: 0.4%;
}
#content-main {
float: center;
width: 77%;
height: 61.3%;
border:1px solid #bbb;
margin-top: 0.5%;
margin-left:23%;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
#content-box1 {
width: 49%;
height: 26%;
margin-top: 1%;
float: left;
}
#content-box2 {
width: 49%;
height: 26%;
border:0px solid #bbb;
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left:51%;
float: center;
}
```

And Here is the code for my main page:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Responsive Web design CSS.css">
      <style>
         a:link {color:#C180E4; font-style: normal;}      /* unvisited link */
         h2 {text-align:center}
         h3 {text-align:center}
         h3 {margin-top:50%}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
         <h2><font size="6">Locked Down Data</font></h2>
      </div>
      <div id="content-box1">
         <p><img src="download.jpg" width="99%" height="94%"      border="1px" alt="picture1"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="content-box2">
         <p><img src="foto-locked-down-iphone.jpg" width="99%"    height="94%" border="1px" alt="picture2"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="content-left">
         <h1><font size="5"> Menu</font></h1>
         <p><font size="4"><a href="Home Page.html"> -Home</a></font></p>
         <p><font size="4"><a href="Page 2 - Threats.html"> -Threats</a></font></p>
         <p><font size="4"><a href="Page 3 - Protection.html"> -Protection</a></font></p>
         <p><font size="4"><a href="Page 4 - Pracitcal Application.html"> -Practical             Application</a></font></p>
         <p><font size="4"><a href="Page 5 - Contact.html"> -Contact</a></font></p>
         <h3><img src="it-security.png" width="79%" height="30%" alt="picture2" /></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="content-main">
         Aenean ac turpis lectus. Vestibulum vel nulla eget libero tristique egestas           venenatis id est. Mauris dictum ac nulla ullamcorper accumsan. Donec ipsum metus, molestie sit amet pretium a, adipiscing ac tellus. Nulla eu ullamcorper enim. Aliquam adipiscing facilisis erat ultrices aliquam. Nam eu libero est. Mauris semper urna rutrum, suscipit erat ut, varius lectus. Aenean ut orci lobortis ante ultricies facilisis. Curabitur tempus orci et eleifend fermentum. Etiam pharetra mauris sed consequat commodo. Quisque at lacus non massa consequat consequat mattis sit amet elit. Aliquam in tellus faucibus, aliquet mi at, faucibus neque.
         <p><iframe  width="56%" height="31%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W90gNMoeY6c"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For accessibility, text (font-size) doesn't respond to any resizing, you cannot do that using only CSS. There are some javascript/jquery script for that. And please, when asking a question, post **only** relevant code

Comment: If your text resized the same way your images do, then anyone on a small resolution would get totally illegible text because it's too small. You can however control the font-size with css media-queries so you can reduce the font to a sensible size on smaller resolutions.

Comment: @Adam oh ya, good idea about media query and font-size but have you any example of that? Should then using many many media queries?

Comment: Most responsive sites only resize layout elements or drawings (canvas/svg), not actual content. People generally still want content to be the same absolute size regardless of how big the screen is (and mobile devices handle content scaling mostly for you). That's why there really isn't a framework that has content resizing built in and why css doesn't really directly support this. You might reconsider what you're trying to do for this reason. When you size things using px or em, the whole point is you're specifying how big it should be regardless of the viewport.

Comment: I normally use write all my css for mobiles / small devices first (at 320px viewport). Then use `@media (min-width: 40.5em)` to overwrite the mobile styles and make everything look good on desktops. Then depending on your requirements you may need to add extra queries in for the bits in between.

Answer (score 2):

The FlowType library (http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Upvoted to even it out - no need for the downvote, as this is a good solution